# <ul> cannot be centerred with media queries

Tags: css

I have spent like 4 hours and still cannot fix it, I have 2 divs, one floated left and one right, in left div I have text and in right I have a <*ul>, when I use text-align:center; based on media query for the left template it works perfectly, but I also want the <*ul> to be centered when the browser width is reduced. Please take a look here and let me know what I am doing wrong and where exactly ? http://goo.gl/OJ5OHt THANKS A LOT to anyone who helps me get out of this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only ways I can see to do this is to add the following to your ul style under your media query:

```
margin: 0 auto;
width: 217px;
```

It needs to be a fixed width.

OR

Change your ul to:

```
text-align: center;
```

And your li and a items to:

```
display: inline-block;
```

Either way should work.

Comment: @Cmorales haha wow!  Almost word for word - great minds think alike so they say ;)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not so much the UL but the children LI, that are floated left.

You have two options:

A)

Set a fixed width to UL and center via margin auto:

```
.social-icons ul {
    margin: 5px auto;
    width: 220px;
}
```

B) Remove the float from the children LI, set them to inline and set their children A to inline-block (and then UL text-align would work):

```
.social-icons ul {
        text-align: center;
    }

.social-icons ul li {
    display: inline;
    float: none;
}

.social-icons ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
}
```